How to get the CounterStrike 2 lobby id?
I have already found the function on the Internet to join the lobby. You can do this via:
steam://joinlobby/730/<LobbyID>/<SteamID>

But unfortunately I can't find the lobby ID. On the internet you can only find many outdated methods to get the lobby ID manually. Also, steam Developer has written a few things about lobbies in general:
https://partner.steamgames.com/doc/features/multiplayer/matchmaking
But I don't quite understand how to use the API for myself, or if it even applies to my use case.
